# Problems with latte art: too thick to draw

Tags: milk, latte, latte-art

I'm using a low-end machine with pressurized portafilter and started two weeks ago to try the latte art.
I'm aware of the basic steps and I have seen a lot of videos but no success at all drawing latte. It always get too thick to draw (that maybe is a air issue, but I even started to use a fork for better mixing it after frothing)

I filmed it so maybe you guys can help me with the most critic parts. [Latte art video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpsjY8waL14)

I'm using this milk: [image: milk]

200ml : 9.1g carbs, 7.1g proteins and 8g of fat, which 5.4g are saturated.

PS: I know I must use the right jug, but I can't find it here, already ordered online.

Comment: It looks like you are pouring just milk and no microfoam. Only at the end a little bit of foam comes out. How are you creating the steamed milk?

Comment: @avocado1 I'm using a low-end pressurized machine which has a frothing wand.

Comment: Did you have any success with the milk jug you ordered online? It seems like that would be the first change you should make.

Comment: It didn't arrive. I guess it got lost in the mail ;(
But I'm trying with a paper cup with a fold, getting better results.

Answer (score 1):

From the video, I agree with the comment that you haven't made enough foam. This is probably mostly due to the small vessel you have. The proper steaming pitcher should hold about twice as much milk and foam as you'll actually use. This gives you the space to spin the milk and create lots of microfoam.

After you have an appropriate pitcher, follow these steps:

1. **Fill the pitcher** to about 1/4 capacity. Submerge the steam wand into the milk and turn on the steam.
2. **Stretch the milk** by drawing down the pitcher in small movements to create some foam. It should sound like the hissing of a cat or tearing paper. Stop making foam when the milk has risen to about 1/3 of the pitcher capacity.
3. **Spin** the milk by holding the steam wand against the side of the pitcher. This should block off one of the jets so the other 2 or 3 jets are all directed towards the center of the pitcher. Try different angles until you find the right spot where the milk really spins in a fast vortex. The spinning will chop up the bubbles smaller and smaller.

*Keep spinning until the milk has come up to temperature. You can use a thermometer or touch your hand against the side of the pitcher; when it's too hot to touch, then it's ready.*

4. **Smack and Swirl** the pitcher. Tapping the pitcher down on the table will pop any large bubbles on the surface. Swirling will loosen up the foam and allow bubbles in the middle to rise to the surface. After a few repetitions you should have a smooth glassy surface on the milk.

Then you're ready to pour. For this I'll defer to [the master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1uL-kvq5Fg)